# django directory apache2 permissions

Tags: django, apache2

Hey I just got apache2 working with mod_wsgi on my django_project directory, which is pretty kool.  However I can only make it work if I set the permissions on my django_project to 
chmod -R 777 django_project  not so nice I believe.

Can anyone tell me what chmod -R xxx django_project I should be running.  Im not too tight on the whole linux-group-permissions.  eg how do I tell what perm-group apache is in?

Thanks,
N

Answer (score 0):

I believe only static directory needs to be writable by Apache in your case and not entire project directory.

You don't need 777 definitely, all you need is apache user (unless you have other user configured in  [WSGIDaemonProcess](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess) directive ) to own that directory.

Running ps -ef | grep httpd will show the user apache is running as. (Some OS may use apache instead of httpd but you get the idea).

Answer (score 0):

Also you can see ls -l /var/www/ and it'll show you user-onwer and group-owner for the directory.
You should make permissions for django_project similar to /var/www/.

And writable permission is necessary for a socket if it's used (in fasctcgi-scheme)

Comment: It depends of by whom httpd process was runned .. if by root it's ok.